# How to count the number of times a number in a list is greater than the number after it?

Tags: python

I want to see the number of times that a number is greater than the number after it, in a list.

```
example = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def lstCount(lst):
    counter = 0
    if lst[0] < lst[1]:
        counter + 1 
        lstCount(lst[1:])
    else:
        lstCount(lst[1:])

    return counter

lstCount(example)
```

This should produce 2, but I am getting list index out of range.

Comment: What happens in your code when you call lstCount(lst[1:]) on the last element? Also, counter is declared locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a base case where the lst is only 1 element. Otherwise when it checks `lst[1]` it will be attempting to check an element that does not exist and you can get an out of bounds error. Additionally `counter + 1` does nothing. I suggest simply returning the value instead of using a counter.

```
def lstCount(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return 0
    elif lst[0] > lst[1]:
        return 1 + lstCount(lst[1:])
    return lstCount(lst[1:])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
it = iterator(lst)
next(it, None)
count = sum(a > b for a, b in zip(lst, it))
```

Or simply

```
count = sum(a > b for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another straight solution:
traverse first n-1 elements and compare current and next element in list.

```
example = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5]
count = 0
for i in range(len(example) - 1):#get size of example then decrease by 1
    if example[i] < example[i + 1]:#visit element by index
        count = count + 1
print count

Output:
8
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your code to increase your answer's quality.

Comment: I think it's straight enough, simply traverse first n-1 elements by index and compare current and next element.

Comment: Great, please add that to your answer because you should assume OP does not have the knowledge of that. In your perspective, think of why OP asked this in the first place.